# manage.py syncdb fails to create tables because they are not there

Tags: django

I have a strange behaviour of `syncdb` and I know that it worked in the past. Since the last time I executed `syncdb` I made changes to my models but the changes were minimal, mostly adding columns to my models. `syncdb` fails now to create a table because it doesn't exist yet. I cannot really understand why.

My django projects has two packages. The first package which I call `remusdb` is more or less a standalone application that uses `django.db.models.Model` for the communication of the database. For applications that use my `remusdb` package I have written a sample `settings.py` file that looks like

```
REMUSDB_DB_ID   = "remusdb"
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            # django.db needs a "default" database
            # make django.db happy.
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME':   '/dev/null',
        },

        REMUSDB_DB_ID: {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME':   'remusdb',
            'OPTIONS': { 'autocommit': True },
        }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS= [ "remusdb.RemusDBRouter" ]
SECRET_KEY = "Make.here.something.random"
INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'remusdb'
)
```

The idea is that this application can determine a database with a custom name and if you include `remusdb` in a django projetc, then you don't need to mix up databases by having to create the `remusdb`-databases in your default database. Hence I also wrote a database router that automatically uses `REMUSDB_DB_ID` for read and write access whenever you use a model from `remusdb.models`.

This works great as a standalone application and I don't have any problems with it. I even created small scripts that run command from `manage.py` like `syncdb`, `shell` and `sqlall`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# filename: remusdb_syncdb

import sys
import os
import re

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        t  = "Usage: %s settings-unix-path\n" % sys.argv[0]
        t += "\n"
        t += "settings-unix-path       The path of the settings module\n"
        t += "                         in Unix-path format.\n\n"
        t += "NOTE: DO NOT USE %s if you are using RemusDB\n" % sys.argv[0]
        t += "inside of a Django application. In this case please call\n"
        t += "python manage.py syncdb && \\\n"
        t += "    python manage.py syncdb --database=<your database name>"
        sys.exit(t)

    settings_list = sys.argv[1].split("/")
    mod_settings  = settings_list[-1]

    del settings_list[-1]
    settings_path = '/'.join(settings_list)
    if settings_path == "":
        settings_path = "."

    mod_settings = re.sub(r'\.py$', "", mod_settings)

    sys.path.append(settings_path)

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", mod_settings)
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    from django.conf import settings

    argv = [sys.argv[0], "syncdb", "--database=%s" % settings.REMUSDB_DB_ID]
    execute_from_command_line(argv)
```

Calling `remusdb_syncdb <path to settings>/settings.py` the database gets created and I can use my application.

Now I want to use `remusdb` inside of my django project which has its own database that I don't want to mix with the database of `remusdb`. I had to make changes of the `settings.py` file according to my sample above and it looks like this:

```
... the usual stuff
REMUSDB_DB_ID   = "remusdb"
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'remusweb',                     # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    },

    REMUSDB_DB_ID: {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'
        'NAME':   'remusdbdev',                             # Name of DB or path if sqlite is used as engine
        'OPTIONS': { 'autocommit': True },
    }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS= [ "remusdb.RemusDBRouter" ]
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'remusdb',
    'monitor'
)
...
```

When I first added `remusdb` as dependency of the django project I created the database `createdb remusdbdev` and executed then `python manage.py syncdb --database=remusdb` and the tables in `remusdbdev` were created.

After two months developing the django application I had to add columns to some tables in `remusdb` and I didn't want to execute the sql code by myself. So I made `dropdb remusdbdev` and running `python manage.py syncdb --database=remusdb` generates now this error:

```
  File "/home/shaoran/devpython/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 52, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "remus_process" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."."last_stop", "remus_process"."last_change" FROM "remus_pro...
```

Well, of course it doesn't exists yet, the point of `syncdb` is that it creates the tables. The funny thing is that if I execute `remusdb_syncdb` (from my standalone app) with django's settings (I have to temporaly remove the `monitor` line in `INSTALLED_APPS`) then `syncdb` creates the tables. After that `python manage.py syncdb` doesn't fail anymore.

Am I missing something here? Why was I able to execute `manage.py syncdb --database=remusdb` in the past and now I get this strange error?

---

While reading over my question before submitting it I thought about how I started the django project in the first place. I created the django project and added the changes in `settings.py` that are needed for `remusdb` to work. *Then* I executed `syncdb` for the first time. Now I have a second package, `monitor` , that has views and templates. So I dropped the database once more, created it again and this time I temporaly removed the `'monitor'` line from `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then I executed `python manage.py syncdb --database=remusdb` and it run without a problem. Next time I repeated these steps but I didn't temporarily remove the `'monitor'` line and the error returned.

What is going on here?

Comment: Syncdb does not support alter table.  You need to look into a 3rd party app called south to achieve that

Comment: I know that, but the problem here is not altering the table but creating it at all. If I remove the `monitor` line of `INSTALLED`APPS` then it suddenly works. I cannot understand why.

Comment: you mean using remusdb in your INSTALLED_APPS create problems?

Comment: No, using `monitor` in `INSTALLED_APPS` creates problems. Without it I can execute `syncdb` with `--database=remusdb`.

Comment: I think you should provide the full exception traceback. Perhaps importing that app executes some code which tries to execute DB query

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also try moving `'monitor'` above `'remusdb'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. It might resolve the problem.

i.e.

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        ...
        'monitor',
        'remusdb'
    )
```